# ErrorOccurrenceTimeSpanTooBig in Microsoft Outlook Calendar API?

Tags: php, laravel, outlook, calendar

I'm trying to integrate the Calendar Outlook API in laravel.

I'm able to create simple events, but when I try to create a recurring event, I get this response:

```
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorOccurrenceTimeSpanTooBig",
    "message": "One occurrence of the recurring calendar  (truncated...)
```

This is the payload that I pass to `json_encode`:

```
array(6) {
  ["subject"]=>
  string(15) "recurring title"
  ["body"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["content"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["start"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-07-28 12:00:00"
    ["timeZone"]=>
    string(11) "Asia/Taipei"
  }
  ["end"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2019-08-05 12:00:00"
    ["timeZone"]=>
    string(11) "Asia/Taipei"
  }
  ["location"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["displayName"]=>
    string(18) "location recurring"
  }
  ["recurrence"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["pattern"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "weekly"
      ["interval"]=>
      int(1)
      ["daysOfWeek"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "Monday"
      }
    }
    ["range"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(7) "endDate"
      ["startDate"]=>
      string(10) "2019-07-28"
      ["endDate"]=>
      string(10) "2019-10-10"
    }
  }
}
```

Which I then pass here:

```
        $createCalendarEventUrl = '/me/calendar/events';
        $graph = new Graph();
        $graph->setAccessToken($this->TokenCacheService->getAccessToken($request));
        $newCalendarEvent = $graph->createRequest('POST', $createCalendarEventUrl)
                        ->attachBody(json_encode($newEvent))
                        ->execute();
```

I found it in Microsoft's Docs, but it's still not clear to me how to fix it.

Comment: It looks like you may have an [invalid date range](https://help.bittitan.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008253468-ErrorOccurrenceTimeSpanTooBig) specifically with your end range of `2019-10-10` which may not include a Monday (which you specified as a DOW  occurrence). HTH

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the reason you are getting the error is because the difference between `2019-07-28 12:00:00` and `2019-08-05 12:00:00` is 8 days, and you are asking outlook to repeat the event weekly.

Can you try setting it to `<= 7 days`?

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason, removing the `start` and `end` keys when `recurrence` is present seemed to fix it. Could it be a conflict between the `start` and `end` keys and the `startDate` and `endDate` under the `range` key?

Comment: That could be the reason, glad you got it fixed.